# "Unknown" error in eclipse while adding maven-jar-plugin maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have multiple maven project. To change where the compiled jar is exported, I'm using `maven-jar-plugin` plugin like that :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${export_dir}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I use "*Maven -> Update project*". Now, I can run the `mvn install` and it will works.

BUT, Eclipse show this error:

[image]

The TOP of the file is :
[image]

The full `pom.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-project</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${export_dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And if I remove this plugin, then update project, the error disappear.

My eclipse version: *Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200* (because it was the last without Java 16 required)

Do you know how can I remove it ?

Comment: Just, I don't know if [tag:java] tag should be on the question, maybe I should remove it from actual tags

Comment: Why do you change the outputDirectory of the maven-jar-plugin that does not make sense.. ? for what purpose? (please use text and no images!)...

Comment: I use this after seeing SO post, and because it works. Also, I show image because there isn't any informations except "Unkown" and the error isn't on specific code

Comment: Maven integration works terrible in Eclipse. Eclipse is notorious about showing errors where there are none. Just ignore it. You can also submit bug report, but then they will most likely ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I was running Eclipse with Java 8.

So, I :

- Update Eclipse as latest (2021-12)
- Use Java 16 instead of Java 8
- Made some changes of Eclipse options because of upgrades

And now, I don't know exactly why but it disappear. I'm thinking it's because of the Java version, but it's not sure.